# How to count values in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

Based on the number of time the number is repeated and count by excel formula or vba

Comment: This question is not very clear or punctuated.

Comment: I usually shorten it to something like `=N(B1)*(A1=A2)+1`

Comment: I am working with 800,000 lines, this formula works faster than the first one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: May you explain me the formula using N function please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Countif with a variable range:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

Put the formula in B2 and copy/drag down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is sorted on ID, this will be more efficient: put in B3 and copy down

```
=IF(A3<>A2,1,B2+1)
```